# How to Get Both Proxy IP AND real remote IP into Nginx and PHP

Tags: php, nginx, proxy

I am trying to get two IP addresses into the headers so I can read them via PHP the proxy/middleman IP and the real remote client IP. Is there a way to get both? I want the real ip in "REMOTE_ADDR" and then the proxy IP in a custom header but it seems if i overwrite REMOTE_ADDR with the real client IP I then cant see what the proxy IP is?

I tried the following in order but it doesnt work. They end up both being the same IP. Any ideas?

```
add_header X-Proxy-Ip $remote_addr;
set_real_ip_from 123.10.20.0/17; 
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Comment: Try: `add_header X-Proxy-Ip $realip_remote_addr;`

Comment: looks like this makes the header show up via a CURL test. But its not showing up in $_SERVER in PHP? Any idea why?

Comment: The values in `$_SERVER` are defined using `fastcgi_param` statements (if you are using `fastcgi` to talk to PHP).